# Create HTML elements from nested array

Tags: javascript

I am attempting to create the mobile view of a restaurant menu. The menu itself is stored in the `menu` variable which holds data in the form of

```
let menu = [
  [
    'Food Section', //i.e Appetizers
    ['Entry', 'Food Description' , 'Price'],
    ['Entry', 'Food Description' , 'Price']

  ]
  [
    'Food Section', //i.e Soup
    ['Entry', 'Food Description' , 'Price'],
    ['Entry', 'Food Description' , 'Price']
  ],
   etc...
```

I want the website itself to display buttons with the food sections ("Appetizers" button, "Soup" button) and upon clicking said button the appropriate food entries will drop down and become visible. For now I am attempting to just create the `buttons` and `divs` of the appropriate entries under each `button`. I do this by looping through `menu` and then looping through each `menu` element. Here is my code:
js:

```
let menu = [
  [
      'Appetizers',
      ['Fried Calamari', "", '$11.95'],
      ['Mussels', "Marinara, fra diavolo or bianco", '$12.95'],
      ['Calamari & Mussels', "Fra diavolo or marinara", '$12.95'],
      ['Hot Antipasto', "Two baked clams, two stuffed shells, two stuffed mushrooms, two fried shrimp & scallops in a seafood sauce", '$14.95'],
    ],
    [
      'Soups',
      ['Chicken Noodle','','$4.95'],
      ['Minestrone','','$4.95'],
      ['Lentil','','$5.95'],
      ['Pasta Fagioli','','$5.95'],
      ['Cheese Tortellini','','$6.95'],
    ]



//create html elements by looping through menu variable
      for(i = 0; i < menu.length; i++){
        for(j = 0; j < menu[i].length; j++){
          if(j == 0){
            foodSectionText = menu[i][j];
            let btn = document.createElement("BUTTON");
            btn.innerHTML = foodSectionText;
            document.body.appendChild(btn);      }
          else{
            menuEntry = menu[i][j];
            console.log(menuEntry);
            for(i = 0; i < menuEntry.length; i++){
              div = document.createElement("DIV");
              div.innerHTML = menuEntry[i];
              document.body.appendChild(div);
            }
          }
        }
      }
```

The above code will create:

```
<button>Appetizers</button>
<div>Fried Calamari</div>
<div></div>
<div>$11.95</div>
```

But then throws `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined` referring to     `for(j = 0; j < menu[i].length; j++)`. Why is the second item `['Mussels', "Marinara, fra diavolo or bianco", '$12.95']` (and all subsequent items) not being properly rendered? Also if you have any suggestions as to how to clean up this process feel free to share, I feel I am going about implementing this a terrible way...

Comment: You're using `i` again in an inner-loop. It breaks your main loop and causes an error on the next iteration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the 3rd for loop, you're reusing the same loop counter `i`. Try using a different variable name (in my example I used `k`)

```
for(let i = 0; i < menu.length; i++){
  for(let j = 0; j < menu[i].length; j++){
    if(j == 0){
      foodSectionText = menu[i][j];
      let btn = document.createElement("BUTTON");
      btn.innerHTML = foodSectionText;
      document.body.appendChild(btn);      }
    else{
      menuEntry = menu[i][j];
      console.log(menuEntry);
      for(let k = 0; k < menuEntry.length; k++){
        div = document.createElement("DIV");
        div.innerHTML = menuEntry[k];
        document.body.appendChild(div);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Should also declare all the variables to be local with `var`

Comment: Good call! Added them